# Passing `Context` everywhere seems messy - create classes to handle different interactions with context?

Tags: java, android, android-context

There are loads of questions which deal with `Context`, which context to use, and how to store it, etc. But I feel dirty every time I pass it to an object, or create a static or singleton that provides access to it. I'm not sure what smell I'm getting, but it definitely smells.

I was thinking an alternative would be to create classes that act as a proxy for a context, which I pass around instead, that defines a subset of a contexts' features as a sort of interface (Not the language `interface` keyword).

An example of an alternative (with code left out for readability):

```
// in activity.onCreate():

    StateStorer ss = new StateStorer (getApplicationContext());
    RememberMe obj = new RememberMe(ss);
    ss.restore();

// in activity.onDestroy()

    ss.save();

// the "proxy"
class StateStorer {
    List<StateStorerListener> listeners;
    Context mContext;
    public StateStorer(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }
    public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String tag){
        return mContext.getSharedPreferences(tag, 0);
    }
    public save(){
        // tell listeners to save
    }
    public restore(){
        // tell listeners to restore
    }
}

// an example class that needs to save state

class RememberMe {
    public String TAG = "RememberMe";
    public StateStorer mSs;
    public RememberMe (StateStorer ss){
        mSs = ss;
        ss.addListener(this)
    }
    // this class would implement the StateStorer's listener interface,
    // and when the StateStorer tells it to save or restore, it will use the
    // StateStorer's methods to access the SharedPreferences object
    public void onRestore(){
        SharedPreferences sp = sSs.getSharedPreferences(TAG);
        // restore from prefs here
    }
}
```

Are there any OOP principles which this goes against? Or smells that it fixes? I just can't decide.

Comment: What would be the difference in passing your `StateStorer` around, or the `Context`? In both cases, the instance you're passing the `Context` (indirectly) to, have a reference to the `Context`.

Comment: Awesome question, I've been wondering for years.

Comment: The Context object seems to do so much, and I always find myself wondering why an object needs a context, and having to go in and see. Perhaps it is simply more explicit. Also it might help avoiding passing the wrong kinds of context for the same reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever passing a `Context` instance to another class, think,

> "*Is it possible that this class will actually live longer than the `Context` I'm passing to it?*"

If the answer is no, don't worry. If the answer is yes, think *why*.

`View`s for example, when used normally, will never live longer than your `Activity`. As soon as the `Activity` gets garbage collected, your `View` will get garbage collected, so there's nothing to worry about.

Singletons however, *do* live longer, and *will* leak the `Context`. That is, when the `Activity` is supposed to be garbage collected, it will not be, because the singleton still has a reference to it.

A couple of solutions come to mind:

- Use `getApplicationContext()` for singletons. This type of `Context` lives for as long as your application lives - thus for as long as your singleton lives.
- Use `WeakReference`s. This ensures that you will not keep an active reference to your `Context`, and avoid leakage. You will however need to compensate for possible nullity of the `Context`.

Obviously, it is required you understand the basics of garbage collection. [Here's an article about that](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx).

---

As for the example code you've given, I see no difference in passing this instance around than passing the actual `Context` around. In both cases you hold a reference to the `Context`. In fact, the `StateStorer` class seems to be a singleton, and - like you did - should be provided with the `ApplicationContext`.

You will also often see that singletons, when supplied a `Context`, call `getApplicationContext()` on it themselves to avoid such mistakes:

```
public static MySingleton getInstance(final Context context) {
    if(sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new MySingleton(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    return sInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like neat code. But why go through all these complex motions just to pass on the context? Seems to me now you are passing on a different class (your RememberMe class) and this is just as bad or good as passing on the context. So I don't really see the advantage.